# Highlight of the current menu item and marking when the submenu item is active

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I want the current page of the navigation including the start page to get the css class "active".
In addition, if a submenu item is selected, the parent menu should also get this class.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
        background-color: #009EE3;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="first-menu"><a href="http://test.local/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="first-menu"><a href="">Menu1</a>
            <ul>
            <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/m1a/">Menu1Sub1</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/m1b/">Menu1Sub2</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/m1c/">Menu1Sub3</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="/m1d/">Menu1Sub4k</a></li>
            </ul>        
            </li>
<li class="first-menu"><a href="/downloads/">Menu2</a></li>

    </nav>
    </div>
```

Comment: please, read [the entries on how/what to ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Show what you have tried, ask about a particular problem/error you've met, etc. SO is not a free code-writing service, so "questions" describing what you "want" are less than enough.

Comment: Please excuse. I have not described my problem sufficiently.

I already tried it with different onclick codes and with the JavaScript code I pasted above.

With onclick I had the problem that with different input pages the first loaded page is not marked correctly. 

With the code I posted here the problem is that it doesn't work for the parent elements and on the home page every subpage is marked blue.